# Recover old backup with barman

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, barman

I have setup barman that allows me to backup my database.

I have several backup, and I would like to recover an old backup. because I need to check the state of the database at a given time, two month ago.

Here are my backups:

```
$ barman list-backup test-server
test-server 20210108T050002 - Fri Jan  8 04:00:11 2021 - Size: 500.9 MiB - WAL Size: 14.2 MiB
test-server 20210107T050002 - Thu Jan  7 04:00:06 2021 - Size: 499.0 MiB - WAL Size: 17.1 MiB
test-server 20210106T050001 - Wed Jan  6 04:00:09 2021 - Size: 497.1 MiB - WAL Size: 10.0 MiB
test-server 20210105T050001 - Tue Jan  5 04:00:10 2021 - Size: 493.7 MiB - WAL Size: 18.0 MiB
test-server 20210104T050001 - Mon Jan  4 04:00:08 2021 - Size: 490.6 MiB - WAL Size: 19.0 MiB
test-server 20210103T050002 - Sun Jan  3 04:00:07 2021 - Size: 490.5 MiB - WAL Size: 274.1 KiB
test-server 20201227T050002 - Sun Dec 27 04:00:11 2020 - Size: 468.0 MiB - WAL Size: 139.1 MiB
test-server 20201129T050002 - Sun Nov 29 04:00:07 2020 - Size: 299.0 MiB - WAL Size: 757.8 MiB
test-server 20201025T050002 - Sun Oct 25 04:00:04 2020 - Size: 84.0 MiB - WAL Size: 850.8 MiB
```

I would like to restore the backup from Nov 29.

I ran `barman recover test-server 20201129T050002 test-server-restore`.

The probem is that the backup I get contains values inserted today. How is it possible ? It's like if I have the backup from Nov 29 +  the all the WAL streaming between Nov 29 and today.

How can I recover a backup exactly from Nov 29 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `barman recover` command tells barman which backup to restore from, but not to which point in time, so you get that backup, plus all the WALs since then.

You need to add a [point in time recovery](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.13/#recover) option to your recover command., such as `--target-time TARGET_TIME`.